# What mathematical property must the Hamiltonian have for the system to evolve to an entangled state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, hamiltonian, quantum-states

For a closed system composed of two subsystems in a pure, non-entangled state, what mathematical property must the Hamiltonian have for the system to evolve to an entangled state?

What property must it fulfill for the system to evolve into a mixed state?

Could you give some examples of both cases?

Comment: as long as the Hamiltonian is not separable (i.e. cannot be written as $H_1\otimes H_2$) then some input state will become entangled after some time